# "minikube start" stops to run on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, minikube, process.start

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to run "minikube start" on my UBUNTU 18.04.
The characteristics of the system are:

- Windows 10 PC with Virtual Box 6.1.16
- In Virtual Box I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 (11GB of memory and 2 processors)
- I've also enabled nested virtualization
- In Ubuntu I also installed (searching with google):virtualbox-dkms and linux-headers-generic

Every time I run

```
minikube start
```

I get the following messages

- minikube v1.15.1 on Ubuntu 18.04
- Automaticaally selected the virtualbox driver
- Downloading VM boot image ...
- minikube-v1.15.0.iso.sha256: 65 B / 65 B [-------] 100.00%? p / s 0s
- minikube-v1.15.0.iso: 181.00 MiB / 181.00 MiB [] 100.00% 6.45 MiB p / s 28s
- Starting control plne node minikube in cluster minikube
- Downloading Kubernetes v1.19.4 preload ...
- preloaded-images-k8s-v6-v1.19.4-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4: 486.35 MiB
- Creating virtualbox VM (CPU = 2, Memory = 2600MB, Disk = 20000MB) ...

and here it stops.

I also thought that the problem was related to the lz4 format and that the machine was unable to decompress the image.
I then installed

```
liblz4-tool
```

but without success.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: My bet the issue is related to the fact of nested virtualization. The issue occurs specifically on the part of creating a `VM`. My interpretation is that something is going wrong in the VM creation process. Do you have a GUI? Can you create a `VM` in your ubuntu virtualbox with 64 bit support? Have you considered using different driver like for example `docker`?

Comment: Could be the problem is the nested virtualization. This mean that I have to use a machine that boot directly in Linux. In any case, serching in internet I used like driver none, virtulbox and doker, without success.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Docker` driver with your minikube on your `Ubuntu` VM that is spawned with Virtualbox?

Comment: I tried without success. The problem, I think, is the nested virtualization

Comment: I found this link: https://webme.ie/how-to-run-minikube-on-a-virtualbox--vm but the out is not equal to the out reports in toutorials

Comment: What error are you getting by following this tutorial?

Comment: Any errors. Only the process stops to the message: "Creating virtualbox VM (CPU = 2, Memory = 2600MB, Disk = 20000MB) .."